# How to access Microsoft Graph API with a SharePoint App-Only registration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to use the Bearer token provided by a SharePoint App-Only¹ registration, to get access for Microsoft Graph features² like Drive list, Excel Create TableRow³, etc?

I was able to get a token using the example "Using this principal in your application without using the PnP Sites Core library", but when I tried to list sites, for example I got not authorized exception

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-post-rows?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Token for SharePoint App-Only and token for Microsoft Graph cannot be used vice versa.

Apps registered in for SharePoint App-Only and Microsoft Graph have different client id, etc.

Also permissions scopes are totally different.